# gold price detection using data mining

Tags: classification, data-mining, predictive-modeling, algorithms, scikit-learn

I have dataset of gold prices and after modifying and some preprocessing i ended up with dataframe below: [image]

There is 50,000 record in dataset and all columns expect `date` are `int` type and `date` is `datetime` object.
i need to predict price per unit in some specific dates. but somehow i baffled with so many methods.

My question is **what data mining algorithm/method is results good prediction for this kind of data ?**

Comment: It is a time series with covariates. I would try first an ARIMAX model

Comment: 50k and only a few columns sounds small enough to be loaded and played with in [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) are quite efficient at dealing with sequential information such as time-series.
[LSTM (Long Short Term Memory)](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) is a type of RNN that can learn long-term dependencies and overcome some problems that vanilla RNNs have.
If you want to try it on your problem, I'd suggest [this tutorial on LSTM for time-series prediction](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/).